# Use of a FLANN index to match a picture with a database

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to match a picture with a database that contains about 1000 images.
I would like that after receiving an image as an input the program returns the most similar picture in the database.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

scanned = 'input.jpg'
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number = 10, key_size = 20, multi_probe_level = 0)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params,search_params)

des_all = None
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    img2 = cv2.imread('images/' + filename, 0)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
    flann.add([des2])
    
print ("Training...")
flann.train()                    

img1 = cv2.imread(scanned, 0)
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
print ("Matching...")
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,k=2)
```

After that what I have to do to get which of my images has the best match?
How can I use the matches results?
I can't find any useful documentation about it
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: You might try using a perceptual hash. See phash at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d93/group__img__hash.html#ga5eeee1e27bc45caffe3b529ab42568e3

Answer (score 0):

for finding the best match I have an idea for each pic enter keys and old pic saved keys:

```py
matches = flann.knnMatch(kp1,kp2,k=2) 

good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)
```

then return each good match and the biggest match is your result
ofcourse Better approach would be using MSER or FAST features present in Matlab. Use their documentation, they literally do what you ask.